# Print json response in php table

Tags: php, json

I need to print json response in php/html table, I am stuck for 4 days..

i have the json response as follows, it displays on the link [http://localhost:8080/fb/?code=AQCtq-HglnDn5OZGCZAgnqiDHgL6fRHIC0054JJs6HgMmqw8h_qNDSqToe4ZxAM6kkGLDIzUaoruR0rfSlSenwRnWNv6Q6TH0Gbf6jbQ73m1uVEYnt_jrPiyawtKvj6bASITtMFC41Lly5SO25NOBRXP00RWN3uQoB3SxOe3ok3eypFZ26IRW1amNhDj3QdknvjpqsrpyhEUwK3NnHkRZmQqCKdvXywcZ-ENRxYAwN1rg4Gt0-fsdpnnKaQNx63MkXm6qEiSyIMPnZVHE7QPAJzIgdmUtK-aJD5lePpoIVJKT9P-Yy0R3ZIB2rHR5OTorx1WUOs5gHI7ANDEQnJN4mB4&state=32c7de5b745a4def2865de6684770d2d#*=*](http://localhost:8080/fb/?code=AQCtq-HglnDn5OZGCZAgnqiDHgL6fRHIC0054JJs6HgMmqw8h_qNDSqToe4ZxAM6kkGLDIzUaoruR0rfSlSenwRnWNv6Q6TH0Gbf6jbQ73m1uVEYnt_jrPiyawtKvj6bASITtMFC41Lly5SO25NOBRXP00RWN3uQoB3SxOe3ok3eypFZ26IRW1amNhDj3QdknvjpqsrpyhEUwK3NnHkRZmQqCKdvXywcZ-ENRxYAwN1rg4Gt0-fsdpnnKaQNx63MkXm6qEiSyIMPnZVHE7QPAJzIgdmUtK-aJD5lePpoIVJKT9P-Yy0R3ZIB2rHR5OTorx1WUOs5gHI7ANDEQnJN4mB4&state=32c7de5b745a4def2865de6684770d2d#_=_)

```
array(3) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(25) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "961716293930505"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "Nena Gomez"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "738589686317947"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Betuxx Chacon"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "10154358290553845"
      ["name"]=>
      string(24) "Gabriel Heredia Briseño"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1568587126490267"
      ["name"]=>
      string(18) "Armando Von Thesse"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "10211420006316586"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "Any Obregon"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1464100830268739"
      ["name"]=>
      string(35) "AarOnn LeOnne Raamiireez Raamiireez"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1210996895614354"
      ["name"]=>
      string(23) "María José Hernández"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "10205997740821868"
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "Mario Martinez"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1898457230384035"
      ["name"]=>
      string(23) "Veronica Ramirez Cuevas"
    }
    [9]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1333307456741256"
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "Nicacio González"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "10210081324343375"
      ["name"]=>
      string(20) "Ariela Ampai Herrera"
    }
    [11]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1383385655027101"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "Leyda Luna"
    }
    [12]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "10154085294360936"
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "Ivan Azael Rivera"
    }
    [13]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1839478686312278"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Isamar Rodriguez"
    }
    [14]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "954280078035568"
      ["name"]=>
      string(32) "Seylin Mariana Brenes Peñaranda"
    }
    [15]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1220976504656199"
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "Yamili Ch Smendez"
    }
    [16]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1231937083552234"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Kennya Huerta"
    }
    [17]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1055827734543856"
      ["name"]=>
      string(22) "Lizarazu Mario Esteban"
    }
    [18]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "692883830880037"
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "Luian Suyos CA"
    }
    [19]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1223005904451888"
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "Rojas Andres"
    }
    [20]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1330174903721200"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Andrey Muñoz"
    }
    [21]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "10210287624562868"
      ["name"]=>
      string(27) "Carlos Manuel Veloz Sanchez"
    }
    [22]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1454728524567426"
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "Brandon Marín"
    }
    [23]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1809382102646429"
      ["name"]=>
      string(27) "Dulce Maria Garcia Alvarado"
    }
    [24]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "244610952637604"
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "Nafancy Soto"
    }
  }
  ["paging"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cursors"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["before"]=>
      string(20) "OTYxNzE2MjkzOTMwNTA1"
      ["after"]=>
      string(20) "MjQ0NjEwOTUyNjM3NjA0"
    }
    ["next"]=>
    string(296) "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/778837615590033/likes?access_token=EAAW6655F9B8BADxO2m3VFKuNs7mEifqLGhDWEBxUtvL9jF8x8ZATLWUl0ZBR6jephQjNpWuuZCbgosbZCZAaNJLxeJ9seTxBQPneYGWMvf2I89ZAt2jOdV3rJu7iemXniCG6LiWDdUyjBl43ocEaRXPTN5qxzlPgcZD&pretty=1&summary=total_count&limit=25&after=MjQ0NjEwOTUyNjM3NjA0"
  }
  ["summary"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["total_count"]=>
    int(28215)
  }
}

likes count 28215
```

and my code is

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ .'/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '1612896019018783',
'app_secret' =>'483a369576ee496cce5780b0d5e23202' ,
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$permissions = ['user_photos'];
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken=$helper->getAccessToken();

if(isset($accessToken)){

    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/778837615590033/likes?&summary=total_count&access_token={$accessToken}";
    //$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1205547979521647?fields=posts{likes,comments}&access_token={$accessToken}";
    //$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1205547979521647?me?fields=id,name&access_token={$accessToken}";
    $header=array("Content-type: application/json");

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;U;
    Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

    $st=curl_exec($ch);
    $result=json_decode($st,TRUE);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";

    $likes = $result['summary']['total_count'];
    echo "likes count ". $likes;
    //echo "<center>";
    //echo "<img width='700' height='450' src= ><br><br>";
    //echo "<img width='90' height='90' src=http://i.imgur.com/wVAJS8T.png";
    //echo "</center>";



}
else
{
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:8080/fb/',$permissions);
    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login with FB</a>';
}


?>
```

I need to display the results in results.php in table format

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $result['data'];

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>id</td><td>name</td></tr>';
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $item['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $item['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    addMysql($item['id'], $item['name']);
}
echo '</table>';

function addMysql($id, $name) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (`id`, `name`) VALUE ($id, $name);";
    // instance mysql driver
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: can i add this values to mysql database??

Comment: i need to store the id and name to the mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Your `$result` is in array format.So just use the table tag as below.

```
$result=json_decode($st,TRUE);
  echo "<table>";
 foreach ($result as $res) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$res['data']['id']."</td">;
     echo "<td>".$res['data']['name']."</td>";
     echo "</tr">;
 }
  echo "</table>"
```

Comment: is there anyway to add json results to mysql database using php?